# refining object array to only latest in group

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I was just wondering if someone could help me out. I have an array list full of objects, each object contains a group number and a date.  What I want to do is create a new array which contains only one entry per group number.  That one and only entry should be the most recent object in that group (using the date value).

For example, the full array could be this:

```
var objectArray [
    {
        groupNumber: '1'
        date: '01/01/2016'
    },
    {
        groupNumber: '2'
        date: '02/01/2016'
    },
    {
        groupNumber: '3'
        date: '03/01/2016'
    },
    {
        groupNumber: '2'
        date: '04/01/2016'
    },
    {
        groupNumber: '3'
        date: '05/01/2016'
    },
    {
        groupNumber: '4'
        date: '06/01/2016'
    },
    {
        groupNumber: '5'
        date: '07/01/2016'
    },
    {
        groupNumber: '2'
        date: '08/01/2016'
    },
    {
        groupNumber: '2'
        date: '09/01/2016'
    },
]
```

but the out come of the new array should be:

```
[
    {
        groupNumber: '1'
        date: '01/01/2016'
    },
    {
        groupNumber: '2'
        date: '09/01/2016'
    },
    {
        groupNumber: '3'
        date: '05/01/2016'
    },
    {
        groupNumber: '4'
        date: '06/01/2016'
    },
    {
        groupNumber: '5'
        date: '07/01/2016'
    },
]
```

Is this possible and if so what would be the most efficient way to accomplish this?  I am using angular but if possible I would not like to bring in any additional libraries.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your input array always sorted by date ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a hash table and [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with exchange if a more recent date is found.

This proposal works with unsorted data.

```js
var objectArray = [{ groupNumber: '1', date: '01/01/2016' }, { groupNumber: '2', date: '02/01/2016' }, { groupNumber: '3', date: '03/01/2016' }, { groupNumber: '2', date: '04/01/2016' }, { groupNumber: '3', date: '05/01/2016' }, { groupNumber: '4', date: '06/01/2016' }, { groupNumber: '5', date: '07/01/2016' }, { groupNumber: '2', date: '08/01/2016' }, { groupNumber: '2', date: '09/01/2016' }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = objectArray.reduce(function (r, a) {

        if (!(a.groupNumber in hash)) {
            hash[a.groupNumber] = r.push(a) - 1;
            return r;
        }
        if ((new Date(r[hash[a.groupNumber]].date)) < (new Date(a.date))) {
            r[hash[a.groupNumber]] = a;
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose a 3 phases algorithm :
1/ sort the array on groupNumber to have elements of same groupNumber be adjascent
2/ just keep elements grouped by groupNumber  which are the youngest
3/ finaly add the last element of the sorted array because it will match

```js
var objectArray = [{ groupNumber: '1', date: '01/01/2016' }, { groupNumber: '2', date: '02/01/2016' }, { groupNumber: '3', date: '03/01/2016' }, { groupNumber: '2', date: '04/01/2016' }, { groupNumber: '3', date: '05/01/2016' }, { groupNumber: '4', date: '06/01/2016' }, { groupNumber: '5', date: '07/01/2016' }, { groupNumber: '2', date: '08/01/2016' }, { groupNumber: '2', date: '09/01/2016' }];
var results = [];
var sortedArray = objectArray.sort((a,b) => a.groupNumber - b.groupNumber);
sortedArray.forEach((x,i,arr) => {
  if (i < arr.length-1 && x.groupNumber !== arr[i+1].groupNumber) results.push(x);
});
results = results.concat(sortedArray.slice(-1));
console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 1):

One might do as follows;

```js
var arr = [
    {
        groupNumber: '1',
        date: '01/01/2016'
    },
    {
        groupNumber: '2',
        date: '02/01/2016'
    },
    {
        groupNumber: '3',
        date: '03/01/2016'
    },
    {
        groupNumber: '2',
        date: '04/01/2016'
    },
    {
        groupNumber: '3',
        date: '05/01/2016'
    },
    {
        groupNumber: '4',
        date: '06/01/2016'
    },
    {
        groupNumber: '5',
        date: '07/01/2016'
    },
    {
        groupNumber: '2',
        date: '08/01/2016'
    },
    {
        groupNumber: '2',
        date: '09/01/2016'
    }
],
    res = [...arr.reduce((m,c) => { var o = m.get(c.groupNumber);
                                    return o ? Date(o.date) > Date(c.date) ? m
                                                                           : m.set(o.groupNumber,c)
                                             : m.set(c.groupNumber,c);
                                  }, new Map())
                 .values()];
console.log(res);
```